# ByteBuffer.get(byte[], int, int) failed on Android ICS and JB

Tags: android

There's strange behavior in ByteBuffer implementation in Android Ice Cream Sandwitch and Jelly Bean. The thing is, `get` method throws BufferUnderflowException. It doesn't in Froyo, GingerBread, Kitkat and Lollipop.

```
    printAndRewind(byteBuffer);
    printAndRewind(byteBuffer);
    try {
        byteBuffer.get(tagIdentifier, 0, 3);
    } catch (BufferUnderflowException e) {
        logger.info("This will be printed in ICS & JB " + e);
        byteBuffer.rewind();
    }
```

This is the printAndRewind method:

```
private void printAndRewind(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
        builder.append(", ").append(byteBuffer.get());
    }
    logger.info(builder.toString());
    byteBuffer.rewind();
}
```

Is it bug? If it is, then how to overcome this problem? I have a library that depends a lot on ByteBuffer. Thanks

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(byte[], int, int) the exception is the expected behaviour when `byteCount > remaining()`

Comment: Does it answer why the problem doesn't happen in GingerBread and Froyo??

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be. My point is that your code is wrong in the first place. You can't speak of a bug if your code is not acting according to the specs. How does your code otherwise know how many bytes were actually copied into  `tagIdentifier` when `byteBuffer` has less than 3 bytes available?

Comment: I'm not a kid in programming. Of course, I already check in the previous lines. I remove checking codes for brevity.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is bug in `java.nio.MappedByteBufferAdapter` class which is an implementation of `java.nio.ByteBuffer` that only happens in ICS and JB. Perhaps, it does in Honeycomb too.

So, in order to prevent the bug, do not use this class.

Use this:

```
byteBuf =  ByteBuffer.allocate(startByte);
channel.read(byteBuf, 0);
```

Instead of:

```
inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
channel = inStream.getChannel();
byteBuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, startByte);
```